# Undefined array key en update imagen y Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy realizando un programa para actualizar una imagen en la tabla de una base de datos en  MySql, el caso es que al actualizar para cambiar la imagen ésta se debe de cargar y eliminar la anterior ya que incluso renombra la imagen al momento de cargarlo, sin embargo tengo el problema que no logro resolver estas alertas

Warning: Undefined array key "imagen" in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\admin\secciones\portafolio\editar.php on line 49

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\admin\secciones\portafolio\editar.php on line 49

Ya tengo la vista cansada y necesito ayuda, les presento el código:

```
<?php 
    include("../../bd.php");
    //Traer los Registros
    if(isset($_GET['txtID'])){
      $txtID=(isset($_GET['txtID']))?$_GET['txtID']:"";
      $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_portafolio WHERE id=:id");
      $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
      $sentencia->execute();
      $registro=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
      $titulo=$registro['titulo'];
      $subtitulo=$registro['subtitulo'];
      $imagen=$registro['imagen'];
      $descripcion=$registro['descripcion'];
      $cliente=$registro['cliente'];
      $categoria=$registro['categoria'];
      $url=$registro['url'];
    }
    //Editar los Registros
    if($_POST){
        //Recepcionamos los valores del formulario.
        $txtID=(isset($_POST['txtID']))?$_POST['txtID']:"";
        $titulo=(isset($_POST['titulo']))?$_POST['titulo']:"";
        $subtitulo=(isset($_POST['subtitulo']))?$_POST['subtitulo']:"";
        $descripcion=(isset($_POST['descripcion']))?$_POST['descripcion']:"";
        $cliente=(isset($_POST['cliente']))?$_POST['cliente']:"";
        $categoria=(isset($_POST['categoria']))?$_POST['categoria']:"";
        $url=(isset($_POST['url']))?$_POST['url']:"";
       
        $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("UPDATE tbl_portafolio SET
        titulo=:titulo,
        subtitulo=:subtitulo,
        descripcion=:descripcion,
        cliente=:cliente,
        categoria=:categoria,
        url=:url
        WHERE id=:id");
        $sentencia->bindParam(":titulo",$titulo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":subtitulo",$subtitulo);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":descripcion",$descripcion);

        $sentencia->bindParam(":cliente",$cliente);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":categoria",$categoria);
        $sentencia->bindParam(":url",$url);

        $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
        $sentencia->execute();
        
        //Validar la actualizacion de la imagen
        if($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]!=""){
           
          $imagen=(isset($_FILES['imagen']['name']))?$_FILES['imagen']['name']:"";
          $fecha_imagen=new DateTime();
          $nombre_archivo_imagen=($imagen!="")?$fecha_imagen->getTimestamp()."_".$imagen:"";
            
          $tmp_imagen=$_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"];
        
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_imagen,"../../../assets/img/portfolio/".$nombre_archivo_imagen);
          
          //Borrado del archivo anterior. 
          $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("SELECT imagen FROM tbl_portafolio WHERE id=:id");
          $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
          $sentencia->execute();
          $registro_imagen=$sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
          
          if(isset($registro_imagen["imagen"])){
            
            if(file_exists("../../../assets/img/portfolio/".$registro_imagen["imagen"])){
              unlink("../../../assets/img/portfolio/".$registro_imagen["imagen"]);
            }
          }

          $sentencia=$conexion->prepare("UPDATE tbl_portafolio SET imagen=:imagen WHERE id=:id");
          $sentencia->bindParam(":imagen",$nombre_archivo_imagen);
          $sentencia->bindParam(":id",$txtID);
          $sentencia->execute();
        }
        
       
    }
    include("../../templates/header.php"); 
?>
```

Tambien les muestro el formulario de edicion:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        Editar Registro de Portafolio
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        
        <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="txtID" class="form-label">Id:</label>
              <input type="text" value="<?php echo $txtID;?>" class="form-control" name="txtID" id="txtID" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Id" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="titulo" class="form-label">Titulo:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $titulo;?>" name="titulo" id="titulo" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Titulo">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="subtitulo" class="form-label">Sub Titulo:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $subtitulo;?>" name="subtitulo" id="subtitulo" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Subtitulo">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="imagen" class="form-label">Imagen:</label>
              <img width="50" src="../../../assets/img/portfolio/<?php echo $imagen;?>" />
              <input type="file"
                class="form-control" id="imagen" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Imagen">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="descripcion" class="form-label">Descripcion:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $descripcion;?>" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Descripcion">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="cliente" class="form-label">Cliente:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cliente;?>" name="cliente" id="cliente" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Cliente">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="categoria" class="form-label">Categoria:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $categoria;?>" name="categoria" id="categoria" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Categoria">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="url" class="form-label">URL:</label>
              <input type="text"
                class="form-control" value="<?php echo $url;?>" name="url" id="url" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Url del Proyecto">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Editar</button>
            <a name="" id="" class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php" role="button">Cancelar</a>
        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">

    </div>
</div>
<?php include("../../templates/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: Cuando mandas un formulario los datos del mismo se serializan usando la etiqueta `name` de los elementos de ese formulario. No pusiste ninguna en el `input` de la imagen, desde agregarle: `name="imagen"`, es cierto que lo tienes en la etiqueta `id` pero esa etiqueta no sirve para serializar el formulario.

Comment: Saludos. Acorde al error que indicas se te presenta; y revisando un poco; creo el error esta en el **if($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]!="")**; te sugiero revises si **$_FILES["imagen"]** existe (es decir lo recibes); puede ese no sea el nombre con que llega (es decir no se llama **imagen**) e incluso que no estas recibiéndola en el php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algo que conviene entender: cuando un formulario es enviado, lo que ocurre es que se crea un array asociativo el cual se almacena en la super global del método del formulario si lo tuviere, en su defecto, se almacena en la super global del método predeterminado, que es `GET`, a no ser que otra cosa haya sido configurada. Esto es para las valores planos como cadenas, números, fechas, etc.

Si el formulario es multipart, los archivos se almacenan en la super globla `$_FILES`, usando también el valor de la etiqueta `name` del `input` que recoge el o los archivos.

Ahora bien, para crear el array asociativo antes mencionado, **se usa como clave la etiqueta `name` de los elementos y como valor lo que haya en `value`**. El motivo por el que `$_FILES["imagen"]` no es encontrado es **porque no pusiste una etiqueta `name` al `input` que recoge los archivos.

Corrigiendo eso en el `input` el problema debería desparecer, y el código debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
          <input type="file"
            class="form-control" name="imagen" id="imagen" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="Imagen">
```

Dicho eso, desde PHP 7 puedes hacer la recogida de tus valores menos verbosa, usando el [*Operador de fusión de null*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), por ejemplo, en vez esto:

```
$titulo=(isset($_POST['titulo']))?$_POST['titulo']:"";
$subtitulo=(isset($_POST['subtitulo']))?$_POST['subtitulo']:"";
```

Con fusión de null, harías esto:

```
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'] ?? "";
$subtitulo=$_POST['subtitulo'] ?? "";
```

En contextos de consulta SQL, deberías controlar que los valores usados en el criterio `WHERE` no estén vacíos, en este caso, dado que usas el valor de `$txtID`, deberías hacer algo así:

```
$txtID=$_POST['txtID'] ?? null;

if($textID) {
    #Aquí recoger los demás valores y preparar la consulta
} else {
    #El valor del criterio es nulo, no tiene sentido la consulta
}
```

Lo mismo deberías hacer con aquellos campos que tienen restricción `NOT NULL` en la tabla y que no tienen definido un valor predeterminado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano por las enseñanzas de recomendacion, me hiciste ver que solo me falto agregar en name en el input,. Un fuerte abrazo, saludos cordiales....